# Windows 10 installation stuck at "setup is starting"

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, installation, ssd

- I checked the disks, they work fine in Linux-live OS (on a USB drive)
- Erased and formatted the disks to NTFS, no luck
- All of the above happened after a force-shutdown of Windows 10 (the system was not responding)
- Tried with other Windows 10 media, no luck
- Even after seeing the "choose partition" window, I was still unable to operate on any of the partitions (even if they have been formatted to NTFS without errors under Linux)

Answer (score -1):

Do you see that disk at setup at all? I suspect issue with drivers or disk.
Check disk in linux with command: `smartctl --all /dev/sda`. Replace sda with sdb or sdc if sda do not work (I don't know you setup when you boot to live linux).
Maybe you need USB stick with drivers to your motherboard, check it on their website? Maybe other disk interfere with installation. Disconnect other disks, USB stick and card reader for installation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the disk is fine, I managed to install Windows with BIOS/MBR, then formatted the disk to reinstall Windows with UEFI, somehow it worked..